# Plotting multiple pie charts from pandas dataframe with labels

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, pie-chart, graph-visualization

I am trying to plot multiple pie charts from a single dataframe, separated by two criteria (two different columns in the datframe)

since plotly.express.pie doesn't have the faceting function, I used plotly.graph_objects but I can't figure out how to re-format the result from a hot mess to a readable form with labels.

I am open to using any and all plotting libraries that produce neat plots.

My code:

```
l = []
for q in range(len(pollutants)):
    l.append({'type':'domain'})
specs = [l]*len(country_codes)
fig = make_subplots(rows=len(country_codes), cols=len(pollutants), specs=specs)
for i, cc in enumerate(country_codes):
    for j, p in enumerate(pollutants):
        df_slice = df.loc[(df.country_code == cc) & (df.pollutant == p)].sort_values('count')
        values = df_slice['count']
        labels = [str(x) for x in df_slice['category']]
        fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=labels, 
                             values=values, 
                             name=f"{cc} : {p}"), 
                      i+1, j+1)
fig.update_traces(hole=0.5, hoverinfo="label+percent+name")
```

Here's the result:
[multiple pie charts plotted with plotly.graph_obects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECUWe.png)

Comment: the code seems to be missing some imports and also undefined variables. for example, what is `pollutants` and `country_codes` and `make_subplots` etc... ?

Comment: There is a subplotting function in plotly.express. `df = px.data.tips();fig = px.pie(df, values='tip', names='day', facet_col='sex', facet_row='time')` I may be able to help if you provide me with the data.